# Select all from table if a value exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following structure.

```
Table A

Name, Address, City, State, enterDate
James, 112 Main St, San Diego, CA, 20150224
Steve, 445 Josh St, Chicago, IL, 20150224
Dave, 158 Dove Way, San Diego, CA, 20150325


Table B

    Name, Address, City, State, JobName
    James, 112 Main St, San Diego, CA, job7
    Steve, 445 Josh St, Chicago, IL, job7
    Mark, 285 Jake LN, San Diego, CA, job7
```

What I would like to do is SELECT everything FROM Table A with a enterDate Between 20150224 and 20150223 but only if the address and city, match an address and city in table B.

I currently do a query to select all from table A where entry date is between 20150224 and 20150223. Then I loop through them and do a query checking if the date exists in table B. I know this is not efficient and is slow.

Is there a efficient way to do this? If so what would the syntax look like?

Comment: Where is your query which you tried from your end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT Name, Address, City, State, enterDate
FROM tableA AS t1
WHERE enterDate BETWEEN '20150223' AND '20150224' AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB AS t2
              WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND 
                    t1.Address = t2.Address AND
                    t1.City = t2.City AND
                    t1.State = t2.State)
```

This query select a row from `tableA` if:

- `enterDate` is between 23-02-2015 and 24-02-2015 **and**
- a corresponding record exists in `tableB` having the same `Name`, `Address`, `City`, `State` fields.

Comment: I tried this but it keeps telling me my Unknown column t1.Address in 'where clause'.... Even though the column does exist